# Android - Listview in fragment not scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I am trying to create a simple listview with items in them. I have done this ton of times but this time for some reason, the scrolling does not work. I am using basic adapter to display items but still it does not work. Been stuck on this for 6 hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated.**The ListView used in the fragment does not scroll.**

The Fragment that has the listview:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

String[] itemsList = {"uguga", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"};
View mView;
ListView mListView;
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    mListView = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.newsFeedListView);
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, android.R.id.text1, itemsList);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return mView;
}
}
```

**fragment_blank.xml**

```
<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
android:divider="#000000"
android:id="@+id/newsFeedListView"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                 tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerItemsListView"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Main Activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ListView mDrawerListView;
NewsFeedFragment mNewsFeedFragment;
ActionBar mActionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initReferences();
    initFragments();
    initProperties();
}

private void initProperties() {
    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xFF326CBB));
}

private void initFragments() {

    mNewsFeedFragment = NewsFeedFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, new BlankFragment()).commit();
}

private void initReferences() {

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerItemsListView);
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
}

}
```

Comment: you should simplify the question, you have 2 `ListViews` in the question. which one does not scroll? the drawer one or the `newsListView`? also if the `newsList` is the one that does not scroll, please add the `Fragment` xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Right. Solved this. The ListView on the MainActivity was taking all the input touches since i did not specify a gravity for that. Once i added

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

to the MainActivity ListView, i was able to scroll.

Comment: Even though the answer is from you, the OP, you should still accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ListView` height to `"match_parent"`.

Comment: Are you using a ScrollView?

Comment: No. Just the listview in the fragment. The problem is very weird.

Comment: If you try to add new items, does it scroll?